# Could the Planeteers use their rings if Capt Planet was summoned?

Tags: cartoon, captain-planet

In Capt Planet and the Planeteers, once each of the kids uses their powers to call Capt Planet, could they still use their power rings to control the elements (and heart)?

I remember wanting to know this when I was a kid and I could never find an episode when they did use their rings after Capt Planet was around, but I never remember the issue being referenced in the show. Then again, it was when I was like 12...

Also, for some laughs: [Don Cheadle](http://youtu.be/TwJaELXadKo)

Comment: And for some more laughs: [Ted Turner Saves Earth](http://video.adultswim.com/robot-chicken/ted-turner-saves-earth.html)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No.  On the TV series, the Planeteers rings were powerless when the good Captain was summoned.

In the episode where he attempted to return to the rings but was unable to do so for two of the Planeteers (they were, as I recall, on the Space Shuttle) he rematerialized with a different color scheme (incorporating only those two colors) and had only their powers - the other rings had their full power restored.

This was quite important for several episodes, which used the fact for dramatic tension - one or more Planeteers were in danger, but since Captain Planet was summoned, their rings were powerless.

Comment: Yeah, I vaguely recall that episode - +1 for the memory :)